# how to get yaml from web api 2 swagger?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, yaml, swagger-ui

This may seem easy to others but I tried many methods that failed and this is so simple I wanted to share. I am using Web API with framework 4.5

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for sharing the tip. SO is a Question&Answer site - could you please transform your post into [Q&A format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) so that it's consistent with the rest of the site? That is, rephrase your original post as a _question_ and post the answer in the Answers section. Otherwise you post might be closed as offtopic/not-a-question.

Answer (score 4):

First run your project and display the swagger by typing /swagger after the address. For example http://localhost:59558/swagger/. The swagger UI will display in a text input a value like http://localhost:59558/swagger/docs/v1. Copy this value and paste it into a new browser window or tab. The swagger data will be returned in json format. Select all the data (Ctl A), copy it (Ctl C) , and paste it (Ctl P) into a text editor like notepad++. Save it as a text file.

go to site editor.swagger.io. From the file drop down select Import File.  Find the file you saved and import it. From the file drop down select save as yaml. The site will save to your download directory named swagger.yaml

Voila done deal easy peasy.

Comment: You can simply paste json into https://editor.swagger.io (left side) and the page will convert it to yaml. (No need to save and import a text file.)